# Umbraco 7: Get fields from same property based on current page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

In my Content section I have a property editor (Archetype) that allows to set content for the site independently from the content tree. It looks like this:

[image]

I need to display only the sub categories from one category based on what page I'm currently on. What I have now is:

```
var catItems = Umbraco.Content(1123).categoryItem; //get the Set Content property editor from Content Section

foreach (var item in catItems)
{
    foreach (var sub in item.GetValue<ArchetypeModel>("subCatItem"))
    {
        <div class="tbl_dt">
            <p class="offerName">@sub.GetValue("offerName")</p>
            <p class="departurePort">@sub.GetValue("departurePort")</p>
        </div>
    }

}
```

This is displaying all the sub category items from all categories. It should display only the sub categories based on current page. How can I make the connection between current page and the sub category item? Or it is best to stick with the property editor in the content tree pages?

Comment: What is the type of `catItems`?  Does it have a property that maps to the associated Page (should be an IPublishedContent).  You can then use that property to check if the `item` is associated with your current page.

Comment: actually the type of `catItems` is `DynamicPublishedContent`. So I should add a content picker to it and map it to a content page? If so how would I check if the item is associated with current page?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not the code, but rather the structure of your Content Tree.
You have nothing to Associate the Category/Offer to the page you want to display it on.

In order to create an the Association between ContentPage & Category/Offer DocType, you could try one of the following:

1. Keep the Category/Offers as they are, independent of the content tree (i.e. Pool of Categories/Offers etc.) 
   Then put a MNTP picker (multi-node tree picker) on the DocType that you want to create the Association between (i.e. 'ProductPage').

Each Page where you want to display the Category/Offer(s) you would need to call the MNTP Picker Property to get the NodeId of that specific Category/Offer for 
the current page.

### Example:

```
var catNodeId = @CurrentPage.pickerPropertyAliasHere; //this will give us the NodeId of that specific offer selected for the current page, may need to refactor your code to handle parsing etc.

var catItems = @Umbraco.Content(catNodeId).categoryItem; //Get Categories/Offers from the Offer picked for the current page.

foreach (var item in catItems)
{
    foreach (var sub in item.GetValue<ArchetypeModel>("subCatItem"))
    {
        <div class="tbl_dt">
            <p class="offerName">@sub.GetValue("offerName")</p>
            <p class="departurePort">@sub.GetValue("departurePort")</p>
        </div>
    }

}
```

2. Put your ArcheType property editor on the DocType you want to Associate with. 
   Then simply call the property for that page and loop over the items again (see example below).

### Example:

```
var catItems = @CurrentPage.categoryItem; //Get Categories/Offers for the current page

foreach (var item in catItems)
{
    foreach (var sub in item.GetValue<ArchetypeModel>("subCatItem"))
    {
        <div class="tbl_dt">
            <p class="offerName">@sub.GetValue("offerName")</p>
            <p class="departurePort">@sub.GetValue("departurePort")</p>
        </div>
    }

}
```

Good Luck
C